# Could you use browserify to require node-bcrypt client-side and then send the hash to the server?

Tags: javascript, browser, node.js, cryptography, bcrypt

Could you use browserify to require node-bcrypt client-side and then send the hash to the server?

Does this just sound really awesome or could it actually provide more security then passing plaintext to the server over SSL? What if we are passing the plaintext via websockets?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

node-bcrypt depends on native OpenSSL support.  In its current configuration, it won't work in the browser. According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299434/bcrypt-implementation-in-javascript), there are no pure javascript implementations of bcrypt, but blowfish, a similar algorithm, does have pure javascript implementations.

For question 2, stick with the standard of TLS (via HTTPS) for your end-to-end encryption.  Chances that your functional requirements require something custom are pretty slim.

Comment: Thanks Peter, right now we are passing this data via websockets (as we are with all data after the initial load) we would like to keep doing that but are unsure of how secure it is. We would either implement a normal POST of the data or client-side encryption. Do you have any more insight on security if we wanted to continue using websockets?

Comment: We also could authenticate the websocket by looping to the client via SSL and passing some unique data back via the websocket trasport. We didn't know how secure this was after the fact though against something like a man in the middle attack. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry I haven't dug into websockets yet, but someone else may chime in.